# indexOf gives false positives

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, find

I made a function to search words in a string given. The function called `str_find` receives the word and then the parameters to search. These parameters can be an array with strings or only a string.

For example, if I call the function like: `str_find("123456789&", ["", "123456789&"]);` it should give me `true`, but for a rare reason sometimes it gives me `false`.

Can you help me please?

My code:

```
    function str_find(word, find){
  if(!Array.isArray(find)){
      if (word.indexOf(find) > 0) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  } else {
      var flag = false;
      for (var i = 0, length = find.length; i < length; i++) {
          if (word.indexOf(find[i]) > 0) {
              flag = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      return flag;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of both String and Array having an `includes()` prototype method

```js
function str_find(needle, haystack) {
  return haystack.includes(needle);
}

console.log(str_find("123456789&", ["", "123456789&"]))
console.log(str_find("foo", 'foobar'))
```

Comment: Hello @charlietfl if i call the function with the parameter console.log(str_find("123456789&", ["", "123456789"])) it gives false, what i need is to return true because it found part of the string

Comment: Try this version then https://jsfiddle.net/n1xhgqfc/

Answer (score 2):

[MDN points out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Return_value) the reason in an obscure way:

> **Return value**
>
> The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the
> provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned.

When the string is found at the very first position of the searched string, it returns a found location index of `0` - which is a falsy value:

Thus your logical test `if (word.indexOf(find) > 0)` returns false when this occurs and gives the false indication that the string was not found, when in fact it was found at the very beginning of the search string.

You can change this behavior by testing for `-1` rather than `> 0`.

Alternatively, you can choose to use other Array methods that are less obscure.

```js
const data = ["", "123456789&"];
const str = "123456789&";
const tests = ["4", "", "123456789&", ";", ["456", "123456789&"]];

function str_find(toFind, toSearch) {
  let found = false;
  if (!Array.isArray(toFind)) {
    if (toSearch.indexOf(toFind) !== -1) {
      found = true;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < toFind.length; i++) {
      found = str_find(toFind[i],toSearch);
    }
  }
  return found;
}
tests.forEach(t=>console.log("test: ", t, str_find(t, data)));
```

Comment: Hello @Randy I have tried to do what you have mentioned but it didn't work. The answer of charlietfl uses includes, the issue of this is that if i pass an array, the word in the array have to been wrotten totally equally

Comment: Please check my edits, they _may_ be closer to your expectations.